# Appropriate use of DL and DD?

Tags: html, validation, semantic-markup

I had some site templates designed for me recently. I got the final HTML code, which validates, but the structure of the document is laid out using DL-DD pairs:

```
<dl>
  <dd class="some-class">
    Some text.
  </dd>
</dl>
```

I'm not especially familiar with those tags as I've never used them much, but they don't seem intended for document structure. Am I right? Why would a designer do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right in that it shouldn't be used like that. The only reason I can think of for the designer using them is that the `<dd>` tag is indented in most browsers. If they're overriding the padding/margins on them, then your guess is as good as mine.

Answer (score 4):

A `DL` tag is about the same as a `UL` tag, it starts an unordered list.

The difference being that there basically is no bullet in a `DL`/`DD` couple.

Most of the time, though, it's used for it's real use, that is, a **D**efinition **L**ist, and is used with `DT` and `DD`, which are **D**efinition **T**erm and **D**efinition **D**escription which would look like :

```
<DL>
  <DT>CSS</DT>
  <DD>Cascading Style Sheet</DD>
</DL>
```

which will, by default, indent the term a bit, and indent it's definition a bit more.

Answer (score 2):

From WC3: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html#h-10.3

> Definition lists vary only slightly from other types of lists in that list items consist of two parts: a term and a description. The term is given by the DT element and is restricted to inline content. The description is given with a DD element that contains block-level content.

So given your example, these types of structures should be used for a specific type of content and not structuring of data that does not fit within this context.

Comment: My main question is, is there any valid reason a designer would use these tags for document strucuture, or is this just WTF code?